# Grails input error: property must be a valid date

Tags: grails

I have a text input that uses custom date and time picker script.

```
<div class="input-group date datetime" data-start-view="4" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-min-view="2" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
    <input name="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="${userInstance?.dateOfBirth}"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
</div>
```

It gives me this error
`Property org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [rms.User.dateOfBirth,dateOfBirth]; arguments []; default message [dateOfBirth] must be a valid Date`

I dont how to solve this. Using the grails dateTime picker tag seems to work but its ugly

Comment: What are you getting in params of action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to use `SimpleDateFormat`. I often use it for forms with a JS-calendar inside:

```
class YourController {

  static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( 'dd.MM.yyyy' )

  def index(){ 
    Date dateOfBirth
    try{ 
      if( params.dateOfBirth ) dateOfBirth = sdf.parse( params.dateOfBirth )
    }catch( Exception ignoreMe ){}
    // do something useful
  }
```

UPDATE:

You must use the propper date format of course. The one I gave in my example `dd.MM.yyyy` corresponds to `08.02.2014`. For strings like `February 08 2014` you are gonna need something like `MMM dd yyyy`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for further info

Comment: i tried that but it gives an unparseable error. my strings are like this btw. January dd yyyy. It gives the full word for the 12 months