# Date parsing unparseable

Tags: date, grails

i tried this snippet from the answer with my previous question [Grails input error: property must be a valid date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627775/grails-input-error-property-must-be-a-valid-date)

```
class YourController {

static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( 'MM dd yyyy' )

def saveUser() {
    def userInstance = new User(params)

    Date dateOfBirth = sdf.parse( params.dateOfBirth ) <-------- this

    if (!userInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "createUser", model: [userInstance: userInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), userInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "showUser", id: userInstance.id)
}
```

My string outputs are January dd yyyy, February dd yyyy, March dd yyyy and so on. Basically the it gives the full month name

Now the error is `Unparseable date: "January 01 2000"`when i tried something like January 01 2000 on my input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
 static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat('MMM dd yyyy')
```

Explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.

Comment: it doesnt work it gives a `Property org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [rms.User.dateOfBirth,dateOfBirth]; arguments []; default message [dateOfBirth] must be a valid Date` I think grails doesnt accept MMM dd yyyy

Comment: try `params.dateOfBirth = sdf.parse( params.dateOfBirth )` before `def userInstance = new User(params)`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.
I recommend you to see how it works in `<g:datePicker>` - default grails tag.
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/datePicker.html

```
<g:datePicker name="my_date" value="${new Date()}" precision="day"/>
```

It sends date to server in separated fields like:

```
my_date="date.struct"
my_date_day="12"
my_date_month="7"
my_date_year="2015"
```

That means you have to split your input field.

It is how i resolved that issue.